# Loading XML locally with AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, bulkloader

I have a project in `Flash Builder` and I use `Bulkloader` to load some configuration files. When I run the project from Flash Builder or in a server, everything works as expected, but when I run the SWF from another location (for example "my documents"), the project can't load the XML.

I'm not sure if this is a security problem or something similar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [this settings manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) to add locations that are safe for your SWF to access data from.

It should end up looking something like this:

[image]

Use the **Add location** feature to add the drive that your **My Documents** folder is contained within.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are developing a `WebApplication` and not an `AIR` desktop application, you are allowed to access either network files or local files, but not the both of them. When you run from FlashBuilder, your program is executing from a SandBox and such restrictions won't apply, how ever when you deploy outside, you will get a security error.

If your application does not need to use any network features, you can specify `use-network=false` as part of the compiler options which will allow you to access local files.

To add/change Compiler options, Right click on your project in Flash Builder, select Properties, then Flex Compiler, and enter the option in Additional Compiler arguments. (I am using Flex Builder 3, so it might be different on the Flash Builder that you are using)

[Flex Compiler Options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html)

Comment: @Jose: Check for your different environments: `trace (Security.sandboxType);`

Comment: thank you both! 
Jens Struwe: I have this message when I trace that: localTrusted
@silverback: How change this line: "use-network=false" is there some place in Flash Builder?